# Help with newbie rogue user

Tags: support, new-users

I was just reviewing late answers when [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/376275/75166) from [this user](https://askubuntu.com/users/215248/shams) was brought to my attention.

At first it thought there is just a problem with his full-quote of the question. Then I saw that he copy/pasted also the first highest-voting answer and didn't provide any new thing by his own. Then I checked his profile and found that he posted two other similar 'useful' answers on two other question.

I feel some action from a moderator is needed in this case :-/

EDIT: Apparently a moderator took care of it. A note from whom ever took action would have been nice.

Comment: He just double posted a request for help (**Edit**: It seems they were both removed, that was fast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*rogue* is quite a subjective term - correct, that the user is a newbie.

As regular members - we should all point the way with appropriate constructive comments as to how to improve.

If in doubt - one of the standard pro-forma comments usually applies.

In this case, this is what I have done for the OP.  Its not usual practice for a specific custom response to the initial flagger, so you wouldn't have got a notification of what action was taken.

If there is a need for hurried action - just drop into the general chat room - usually one of the mods lurks in there.

Comment: I edited the first answer and erased the full-quote of the question and then recognized, that he copy-pasted all of it. I then commented asking him why he's doing it. Then flagged the question for moderation. Then I saw, that he was doing it on the two other answers and posted here, because I was unable to comment his other questions. I was already fuming with rage when I saw the mess.